# how to excute entity framework trace sql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6, linq to query mysql. I trace linq generated sql string in debug window like below:

```
INSERT INTO XXX(ID, Name, ...)
VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, NULL, :p8)
-- p0: 'ff641c20dac54f68a76ee7d30a8c39e1' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 32)
-- p1: 'M310000157' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 10)
-- p2: 'FY310000000201812000009' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 23)
...
```

Now I want to debug this sql in some mysql client to get more detail like explain how index used. But I cannot directly run the trace sql.

Is there any easy way that I can excute the trace sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any command sent from EF to the database is logged. To view the generated queries from EF 6.x, use the `DBContext.Database.Log` property

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception